# SetWindowPos compile error in 64-bit Windows

Tags: c, winapi, visual-studio-2012

I'm currently changing our codebase to make it compile under 64-bit architecture.  Most of the changes I'm having to make are obvious, but this one has got me stumped.  `SetWindowPos` has a second argument, `hWndInsertAfter`, that can be either a window handle, or one of the predefined values `HWND_TOP`, `HWND_BOTTOM`, `HWND_TOPMOST` and `HWND_NOTOPMOST` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for MSDN info).  These values are defined in `WinUser.h`.

In 32-bit architecture, using one of those in a call to `SetWindowPos` works fine, but in 64-bit, the compiler complains thus:

> warning C4306: 'type cast' : conversion from 'int' to 'HWND' of
>   greater size

This is because the #defines are casting [32-bit] integers as HWNDs, e.g.:

`#define HWND_TOPMOST ((HWND)-1)`

What do I need to change to make this compile in 64-bit architecture without the compiler throwing a warning?  I can disable the warnings using `#pragma warning( disable: 4306 )`, or make my own definition using a 64-bit int in the #define, but surely there's a "proper" Microsoft way of doing this?

Comment: Something is wrong here. HWND_* are cast to HWND, so it should just work. What happens if you replace it with (HWND)-1 manually?

Comment: It complains.  If I change it to `(HWND)-1i64`, it's happy...

Comment: I found [this link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736183/hwnd-bottom-warning). Seems like it's a bug of VS/the SDK, and it's fixed in the latest versions.

Comment: Well found!  But I'm running the latest update of VS2012 already.  Do I need to update to VS2013?...

Comment: We don't get this warning in either VS2008 or VS2012.

Comment: Make sure to have the SDK include paths set up properly. The order is important. The latest Windows SDK should be at the very top of the list.

Comment: Ok, let me try with the SDK include path at the top of the include list...

Comment: Nope, that hasn't worked.  The SDK include was below the VCInstall path, so moved the SDK path to the top, but it's made no difference.

Could this be in any way related to my compiling 64-bit code on a 32-bit OS?...

Comment: I tried really hard to JUST SEE that warning, with VS2008, VS2010 and VS2012. to no avail. Very curious to know how you do that. Consider providing more infos on your build methods and parameters.

Comment: I have the project's "Warning Level" set at Level4 (/W4) and "Treat Warnings As Errors" to Yes (/WX).  Not sure what other build methods/parameters would be applicable?...

Comment: Could you reproduce with a "3 lines" brand new projet/solution? Could you post the full C++/Command lines panel's content? Could you reproduce with a simple typedef void* FOO; FOO foo=((FOO)-1);?

Comment: And could you use /nologo- and post banner from the C++ compiler?

Comment: Ok, let me see what I can do.  Will post any info I can get as edits in the original question.

Comment: Ok, creating a new project and calling this, it compiles without error.  I've checked every project setting is identical.  So not sure where to go from here...

Comment: I've found the problem.  My file was a C file.  My test app that compiled ok was a C++ file.  It looks like C files don't want to allow casting of 32-bit ints to 64-bit pointers, but C++ files have no problem doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after MUCH testing, the problem was that my file was a .c file.  I renamed it to .cpp and SetWindowPos then compiled without error (and conversely, in the new test app I created to try a 'bare bones' solution, when I renamed the default .cpp file to a .c file, it started complaining).

Looks like .c files don't want to be able to cast 32-bit `int` values to 64-bit pointers.  Which makes sense, but doesn't explain why it works in .cpp files.  If anyone has any ideas on why this is, do note it in the comments...

Comment: [This post](http://alfps.wordpress.com/the-no_sillywarnings_please-h-file/) explains how `/Wp64` led to bogus warnings in legitimate C++ code under MSVC 2008. Apparently Microsoft eventually disabled it for C++ code (where most of the false positives were) but left it enabled for C code. Anyway, modern versions of MSVC apparently ripped it out entirely, so you could always upgrade. (To Clang. ;))

Comment: Am tempted to upgrade to VS2013 to see if it gets rid of the warning.  Will see if I can find time to do that. :)  Thanks for the link - very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is triggered because you're casting the 32-bit `int` value `-1` to a 64-bit pointer type `void*` without any intervening cast to a 64-bit integer type such as `intptr_t`. MSVC *should* have suppressed the warning in this case since (A) it's triggered only by the expansion of the system-provided macro `HWND_TOPMOST` and (B) the offending `int` is a decimal literal, but apparently MSVC's developers didn't think of those heuristics.

There's nothing you can do in your code to silence the warning, unless you're happy with

```
#undef HWND_TOPMOST
#define HWND_TOPMOST ((HWND)(intptr_t)-1)
```

Alternatively, you can try to suppress it in the IDE. [This thread](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/265290-compiler-warnings-casting-int-hwnd) suggests

> Project Settings | C/C++ | General and turn off "Detect 64-bit portability issues"

or pass `/wd4306` on the command line.

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm doing: undefining it, then redefining it as -1i64.  I *could* suppress the warning with the pragma I noted in my question, but I prefer to get to the root of the problem before having to ignoring warnings.  They're there for a reason (most of the time).

Comment: @NickShaw, I can't tell from your comment whether you're saying you still don't understand the reason for the warning. As I say in this answer, it's a "64-bit portability" warning triggered by implicitly converting a 32-bit integral type to a 64-bit type. Should I expand on some part of that explanation?